# cmake linking libraries with internal dependency

Tags: cmake

First of all, I'm not sure if the way I setup my project is correct but it's like this,

A cmake project called Lib has two subdirectories Animal and Dog. Both are static libraries but Dog depends on Animal.

Lib's CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

project(Lib VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "My package." LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(Animal)
add_subdirectory(Dog)

install(EXPORT LibConfig
    FILE LibConfig.cmake
    NAMESPACE Lib::
    DESTINATION lib/Lib/cmake
    )
```

Animal/CmakeLists.txt

```
set(TARGET_NAME Animal)

add_library(${TARGET_NAME}
    src/Animal.cpp
    )

target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    )

install(TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME} EXPORT LibConfig
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    )

install(DIRECTORY include/
    DESTINATION include/${TARGET_NAME}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp")
```

Dog/CMakeLists.txt. I'm not sure how to depend on Animal.

```
set(TARGET_NAME Dog)

add_library(${TARGET_NAME}
    src/Dog.cpp
    )

target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Animal/include>
    )

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    Animal
    )

install(TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME} EXPORT LibConfig
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    )

install(DIRECTORY include/
    DESTINATION include/${TARGET_NAME}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp")
```

This uses the library.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(UseLib)

find_package(Lib REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Lib::Dog
    )
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Dog/Dog.hpp>

int main()
{
    Dog d;
    return 0;
}
```

The libraries compile fine but when I use it in a project I get an error saying Dog can't find the Animal header.

```
.../include/Dog/Dog.hpp:3:10: fatal error: Animal.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "Animal.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/UseLib.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/UseLib.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/UseLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why do you perform `PRIVATE` linkage - `target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE  Animal)` - if `Animal.hpp` is actually included into the **interface** of the `Dog` library? (The library `Dog` has interface header `Dog.hpp`. Since that header includes `Animal.hpp`, then `Animal.hpp` is interface for `Dog` too.) Use `PUBLIC` linkage instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dog is not finding Animal because in Dog.hpp I have `#include "Animal.hpp"` but I have the headers installed in its own subdirectory so external projects includes it this way `#include <Animal/Animal.hpp>`. It's something I didn't understand.

```
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/Animal>
        )
```